# Push player away from object smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So currently I have the basic code working. The player gets pushed away when a certain range is met. However. It's like the player is running against a wall when I'm going right at it.

How should I make it smoother?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlanetPush : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] float range = 1000;
    [SerializeField] float pushingspeed = 10f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        //Check if is in range
        if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) < range)
        { 
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position, Color.green);

            //Push away from object
            target.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(target.position, transform.position, Time.deltaTime * -pushingspeed);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position, Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite easy actually. I had to rampup the pushing speed equal to my maximum player speed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlanetPush : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] float range = 1000;
    [SerializeField] float pushingspeed = 0.01f;
    [SerializeField] float DampSpeed = 0.1f;
    float MaxPlayerSpeed = 30f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        //Check if is in range
        if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) < range)
        { 
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position, Color.green);
            pushingspeed += DampSpeed;
            if (pushingspeed >= MaxPlayerSpeed)
            {
                pushingspeed = MaxPlayerSpeed;
            }
            //Push away from object
            target.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(target.position, transform.position, Time.deltaTime * -pushingspeed);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position, Color.yellow);
            pushingspeed = 0.1f;
        }
    }
}
```